# How to get count of all non NA values for all variables by group?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, na

If I have a dataframe like this:

```
size    P1  P2  P4  P3  P5
> 5K    3   3   NA  NA  NA
> 5K    3   3   NA  NA  NA
> 5K    2   2   NA  NA  NA
> 5K    4   3   NA  NA  NA
> 5K    3   3   NA  NA  NA
> 10K   4   4   NA  NA  NA
> 10K   5   4   NA  NA  NA
> 10K   4   3   4   4   NA
> 10K   3   3   3   3   1
> 10K   4   3   NA  NA  NA
```

which I created as `df <- df %>% group_by(size)`, how can I get the total counts of each variable for each group like below?

```
size    P1  P2  P4  P3  P5
> 5K    5   5   0   0   0
> 10K   5   5   2   2   1
```

I tried several different method using group, but not produced the result I wanted:

For example:

```
aggregate(test[, 2:6], list(test$size), apply(test[,2:6], 2, function(x){sum(!is.na(x))}))

Error in match.fun(FUN) : c("'apply(test[, 2:6], 2, function(x) {' is not a function, character or symbol", "' sum(!is.na(x))' is not a function, character or symbol", "'})' is not a function, character or symbol")
```

Then this:

```
(p1 <- test %>% group_by(size) %>%
summarise(`P1` = sum(!is.na(`P1`))) %>% mutate(size = as.factor(size)))
(p2 <- test %>% group_by(size) %>%
summarise(`P2` = sum(!is.na(`P2`)))%>% mutate(size = as.factor(size)))
(p3 <- test %>% group_by(size) %>%
summarise(`P3` = sum(!is.na(`P3`))) %>% mutate(size = as.factor(size)))
(p4 <- test %>% group_by(size) %>%
summarise(`P4` = sum(!is.na(`P4`))) %>% mutate(size = as.factor(size)))
(p5 <- test %>% group_by(size) %>%
summarise(`P5` = sum(!is.na(`P5`))) %>% mutate(size = as.factor(size)))

count <- count %>% left_join(p2, by = "size") %>%
          left_join(p3, by = "size") %>%
          left_join(p4, by = "size") %>%
          left_join(p5, by = "size")


Error in UseMethod("left_join") : no applicable method for 'left_join' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

I added `mutate(size = as.factor(size))` thinking that without it was why I got the above error. But adding it didn't help either.

So, the only way I could think of doing is:

```
cbind(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)
```

but I feel like there has to be a better way to handle this.

Comment: What exactly are you counting?

Comment: I'm counting the number of responses for each variable by group. Exactly like what you've shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `dplyr` >= 1.0.0:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(size) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), ~sum(!is.na(.))))
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  size     P1    P2    P4    P3    P5
* <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 10K       5     5     2     2     1
2 5K        5     5     0     0     0
```

To get the exact output as OP's:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(size) %>% 
   summarise_all(~sum(!is.na(.))) %>% 
   arrange(desc(size)) # weird(ironic?) though
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  size     P1    P2    P4    P3    P5
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 5K        5     5     0     0     0
2 10K       5     5     2     2     1
```

For dplyr versions below 0.8.9.9000:

```
 df %>% 
   group_by(size) %>% 
   summarise_all(~sum(!is.na(.)))
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  size     P1    P2    P4    P3    P5
* <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 10K       5     5     2     2     1
2 5K        5     5     0     0     0
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(size = c("5K", "5K", "5K", "5K", "5K", "10K", 
"10K", "10K", "10K", "10K"), P1 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 4L), P2 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    P4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, NA), P3 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, NA), P5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to do and struggling like crazy

Answer (score 2):

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
d <- setDT(d)

d[, lapply(.SD, function(x)sum(!is.na(x))), by=size]

   size P1 P2 P4 P3 P5
1:   5K  5  5  0  0  0
2:  10K  5  5  2  2  1
```